# How can I check for matching rows and columns with Python?

Tags: python

I am building a ticTacToe game and I have everything figured out but how to check for three in a row or three down a column. I think there is something simple missing, but I could have it wrong entirely. Here is the code:

```
def isWin(gameBoard):
    #check for row matches
    for row in range(0, 3):
        if gameBoard[row][0] == gameBoard[row][1] and gameBoard[row][0] == gameBoard[row][2]:
            return True
```

Comment: That should correctly detect if all items in one row are the same, although it could be simpler, e.g. `gameBoard[row][0] == gameBoard[row][1]  == gameBoard[row][2]`. Now you have to add a check for columns and a check for diagonals. Don't forget to also check that it you are not in fact detecting that all cells in a row are empty and thus equal.

Comment: the empty cells were exactly what I was running into! I am going to post a comment with the full code of the program because I am SO PROUD. I am new to this so it feels like a huge accomplishment :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider to use set? Something like:

```
def isWin(gameBoard):
    for row in gameBoard:
        if len(set(row)) == 1:
            return true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out!

```
def isWin(gameBoard):

#check for row and column matches
for row in range(0, 3):
    if gameBoard[row][0] == "X" and gameBoard[row][1] == "X" and gameBoard[row][2] == "X":
        return True
    if gameBoard[row][0] == "O" and gameBoard[row][1] == "O" and gameBoard[row][2] == "O":
        return True
    if gameBoard[0][row] == "X" and gameBoard[1][row] == "X" and gameBoard[2][row] == "X":
        return True
    if gameBoard[0][row] == "O" and gameBoard[1][row] == "O" and gameBoard[2][row] == "O":
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out and am super excited! I am new to coding so thank you all for the support! Please let me know if you think it could be more efficient. :) 
Here is the full code:

```
import sys

def main():
    gameBoard = [[" ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " "]]
printBoard(gameBoard)

while True:
    #
    playerXturn(gameBoard)
    printBoard(gameBoard)
    if isWin(gameBoard):
        print("Player X wins!")
        sys.exit()
    elif boardFull(gameBoard):
        print("Draw. No more plays left.")
        sys.exit()

    playerOturn(gameBoard)
    printBoard(gameBoard)
    if isWin(gameBoard):
        print("Player O wins!")
        sys.exit()
    elif boardFull(gameBoard):
        print("Draw. No more plays left.")
        sys.exit()

def printBoard(gameBoard):
    print("---------")
    print(gameBoard[0][0], "|", gameBoard[0][1], "|", gameBoard[0][2])
    print("---------")
    print(gameBoard[1][0], "|", gameBoard[1][1], "|", gameBoard[1][2])
    print("---------")
    print(gameBoard[2][0], "|", gameBoard[2][1], "|", gameBoard[2][2])
    print("---------")

def playerXturn(gameBoard):
    playerXrow = int(input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player X: "))
    playerXcolumn = int(input("Enter a column (0, 1, or 2) for player X: "))

    while gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] == "X" or gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] == "O":
        print("This spot is already taken. Try again:")
        playerXrow = int(input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player X: "))
        playerXcolumn = int(input("Enter a column (0, 1, or 2) for player X: "))

    gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] = "X"

    return gameBoard

def playerOturn(gameBoard):
    playerOrow = int(input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player O: "))
    playerOcolumn = int(input("Enter a column (0, 1, or 2) for player O: "))

    while gameBoard[playerOrow][playerOcolumn] == "X" or gameBoard[playerOrow][playerOcolumn] == "O":
        print("This spot is already taken. Try again:")
        playerOrow = int(input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player O: "))
        playerOcolumn = int(input("Enter a column (0, 1, or 2) for player O: "))

    gameBoard[playerOrow][playerOcolumn] = "O"
    return gameBoard

#check for empty spaces on the board
def boardFull(gameBoard):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if gameBoard[i][j] == " ":
                return False
    return True

#check for 3 in a row
def isWin(gameBoard):
    #check for row matches
    for row in range(0, 3):
        if gameBoard[row][0] == "X" and gameBoard[row][1] == "X" and gameBoard[row][2] == "X":
            return True
        if gameBoard[row][0] == "O" and gameBoard[row][1] == "O" and gameBoard[row][2] == "O":
            return True
        if gameBoard[0][row] == "X" and gameBoard[1][row] == "X" and gameBoard[2][row] == "X":
            return True
        if gameBoard[0][row] == "O" and gameBoard[1][row] == "O" and gameBoard[2][row] == "O":
            return True

    #check for diagonal matches
    if gameBoard[1][1] != " " and gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard [1][1] and gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard [2][2]:
        return True

    if gameBoard[1][1] != " " and gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard [1][1] and gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard [2][0]:
        return True

    return False

main()
```